# RSA encryption using X509Certificate2 keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rsa

i'm trying to encrypt a string before store database i use encrypt decrypt method as follow

```
private static readonly X509Certificate2 Cert = GetCert();

private static X509Certificate2 GetCert()
{
    if (Store == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Store is null");
    }


    Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var collection = Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "TestCert", false);
    if (collection == null || collection.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("No certs in store");
    }

    X509Certificate2 certificate = collection.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(cert => cert != null && cert.HasPrivateKey);

    if (certificate == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Cert is null");
    }

    Store.Close();

    return certificate;
}
```

For Encryption

```
public static string Encrypt(this string plainText)
{
    using (var rsa = (RSACng)Cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
    {
        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        var encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(data,RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
}
```

For Decryption

```
public static string Decrypt(this string cipherText)
{
    using (var rsa = Cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
    {
        var data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        var encrypted = rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encrypted);
    }
}
```

problem is when i decrypt .. throws an exception saying

> WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist

[image]

What was the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors and paste your error as text :)

Comment: `WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist` this is the error. the image was a stack trace. thanks anyway

Comment: Are you sure that your certificate contains a private key?

Comment: @Hyarus when i tried with `Cert.HasPrivateKey` it returns true

Comment: @Gayan might be a permission problem, does your executing user have permission to read the file containing the private key? Otherwise try using non extension methods: *RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()* and importing the key via xml *rsa.FromXmlString(Cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true))*

Comment: "paste your error as text" means for me (sorry about that!), that you should edit your question, so everybody can see it in the first place ;)

Comment: @Hyarus Thanks for the info. The issue was Visual studio needs to start with admin privileges otherwise it will not the private key. once I did it worked. thanks again.